# Angular How to make subscribe wait for a call to finish

Tags: angular, get, rxjs, httpclient

**INSERT NOTE:** This question is not the same as most of the other questions relating to stuff like "How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?" because of the fact that it uses SUBSCRIBE. As far as I understand it, subscribe tells it to do something whenever this thing is changed, therefore you cannot put code inside the subscribe, because it will only ever run when it gets changed (which will always be too late). Please only answer if you have knowledge of Angular, Subscribe and the HttpClient. Now my original question:

I have a problem where I loop through an array and do a get call for each item in the array. My problem is that all these get requests happen asynchronously, which means they all try to get while the previous gets are still receiving their responses. This causes an error. Here is a rough example:

```
 this.MyArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];   

 this.MyArray.forEach(element => {
      this.httpClient.get('http...')
      .subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
      })
 )}
```

How do I let the forEach loop wait for the call response before moving on to the next item in the loop? I tried looking at responses but I just can't understand it :(

Comment: Which error do you get when executing?

Comment: This is a promise observable problem. I don't see a solution unless you know what your observable is going to return.

Answer (score 1):

You can map your array into observable streams. Then you can use `concat` operator to execute the observables in a row.

```
import {
  concat
} from 'rxjs/observable/concat';


this.MyArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const observables: Observable<any>[] = this.myArray.map(() => this.httpClient.get('http...'));

concat(...observables).subscribe(resp => {
  // handle responses, they will execute one after another,
  //  each waiting for the previous one to finish
})
```

Comment: I don't think this works Tomasz. What happens here is that all the get calls are done one after another, and then their subscribe values get filled one after each other. So your order is 4 get calls and then 4 subscription responses. Not 1 get, 1 response, 1 get, 1 response...which is the order I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
this.totalCount = this.MyArray.length;
this.i=1;

getData(){

 let ob = this.MyArray[this.i-1];

 this.httpClient.get('http...')
      .subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
            this.i++;
             if(this.i <= this.totalCount){
               getData()
             }
      })
}
```